# Unexpected <tr> when looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have an array of arrays `@iterated_orders` like this:

```
[[1, "Don", 3], [nil, nil, 4], [2, "Vri", nil]]
```

And code in my view like this:

```
    %table
      - @iterated_orders.each do |day, day_name, order_id|
        - unless day.blank?
          %tr
            %td.day= day
        %td= order_id
```

I would expect it to output this html:

```
<tr>
  <td class="day">1 Don</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="day">2 Vri</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

But it outputs this HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="day">1 Don</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="day">2 Vri</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Why is there an extra `<tr>` and is the `<td>` with the order_id not added to the existing `<tr>`?

Comment: Format the haml snippet properly as haml works on indentation we will not be able to help if it's not clear

Comment: Where are you outputting `day_name`, it isn't in the loop.

Comment: `day_name` would be attached to `day` in the same `<td>`, but for the problem it is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Haml actually renders:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='day'>1</td>
  </tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <tr>
    <td class='day'>2</td>
  </tr>
  <td></td>
</table>
```

When you view it in a browser, the browser will correct this to be valid HTML, including adding extra `tr` elements, which I suspect is where you are seeing your result (although I get something different in Chrome).

The `td` with the `order_id`s are not added to the previous `tr` because that `tr` has been closed at that point. Your Haml reads as “unless `day` is blank, insert a new row containing a cell with the day (and close it), and then insert some table cells with the `order_id`s”.

The best way to achieve what you are trying to do with Haml is to first get your data into a form that matches your intended output. Being familiar with the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) methods can help here. In particular in this case [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) is probably what we want:

```
@sorted_orders = @iterated_orders.chunk_while {|before, after| after[0].blank? }
```

Now you can iterate over this structure to produce the HTML:

```
%table
  - @sorted_orders.each do |day|
    %tr
      -# the first sub-array contains the day:
      %td.day #{day[0][0]} #{day[0][1]}
      -# then add a td for each order_id (including the first):
      - day.each do |d|
        %td= d[2]
```

This produces (with your example data):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='day'>1 Don</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='day'>2 Vri</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which isn’t exactly what your goal is (you have an extra `td` in the second row). You may have to fix the data a bit more to get equal numbers of elements for each day.

Comment: Thanks! I always forget about the implicit closing tag!